# Run Apache Ignite in Docker container as non-root user

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ignite

"Lock is being held to root directory" error when running Ignite container as non-root user.

Created new user and gave user permission for $IGNITE_HOME (/opt/ignite) recursively.

```
Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start processor: GridProcessorAdapter []
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:990)

... 5 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: **Unable to start under DB storage path [/opt/ignite/persistence]. Lock is being held to root directory**
```

Should not get "lock" error

Comment: Without knowing the contents of your kubernetes descriptors, there is no way we can help you. Are you running a custom docker image? Are you volume mounting a hostPath? Persistent Volume Claim? Other? We cannot guess.

Comment: Custom Docker image mounting PV/PVC

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure `/opt/ignite` is writable by the user which runs Ignite.
- Enable INFO logging and search for "Unable to acquire lock to file" messages, which have more precise reason.
- Make sure you're not starting more than one node on the same FS!
- Maybe there are some lock files remaining, owned by root. Delete them.